# Multiple client and single server handling

Tags: c++, sockets

Will this approach work?

I am gonna simply present my code in simplified form for easier readability.
I am trying to implement a multiple client/one TCP server.

My listener will loop like this(as a thread) which handles **connections**

```
void WaitAndAcceptConnection(){


    if(socket_TEMP = accept(sock_LISTEN, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, &AddressSize))
    {

        socketsManager.push_back(socket_TEMP);
        currCount++;

        std::cout<<"\n  A connection was found!"<<std::endl;  

        send(socketsManager[currCount], "Welcome! you have connected to Athena Server", 46,NULL);

    //  cond.notify_one();                                  //notify the waiting thread  
    }


}
```

wherein i have..

```
std::vector<SOCKET> socketsManager;  //handles socket
int currCount=-1; //keep track on the number of connections
```

If a client connected then currCount will be increased by one, in our case it's gonna be `currCount = 0` and then `socketsManager[0]` will store the accept's return. If another one connected then `currCount = 1` then `socketsManager[1]` will be its handler.

**For sending and receiving data.**

I am gonna make a for loop that will continue on iterating to check if there is a recv'd data(-1 or 0) for every sockets that is being handled by my program.

```
void WaitAndAcceptCommands(){
for(int i = 0; i<= currCount;i++){


    int result = recv(socketsManager[i],&command,1,0);
    if(result ==-1){

    }



    else if(result == 0){                               

    }


    else{
    //process commands
    }
}
}
```

**Main** will be something like this

```
Athena ath2;     //instance of the server


std::cout<<"\n >Waiting for incoming connections..."<<std::endl;

//listener thread, just keep on LOOPING
std::thread connectionThread([&](){
    while(1){

    ath2.WaitAndAcceptConnection();

    }
});



//handles all the inputs, JUST KEEP ON LOOPING
std::thread commandsThread([&](){
    while(1){

        ath2.WaitAndAcceptCommands();
    }
});

connectionThread.join();    //stop 
commandsThread.join();      //stop
```

I would gladly show the rest of my code but they are in a complete mess right now. I only wanted to present the idea if this will work and then i will continue on it, if not then i will reconsider another method. I plan on handling my connections through `timeouts` if i will ever have to drop a socket from my `std::vector<SOCKET> socketsManager;` by using remove. Is this a good method? if not then what are the issues?

Comment: Reading about `select` atm but i am kinda confused on how it works.

Comment: There are 2 ways to tackle it. The easier is to use the default blocking I/O, loop on accept and create a new thread for each accepted connection. The second method is to use non-blocking I/O and use `select()` or `poll()`. Non-blocking I/O times out or returns with FDs set. It is your responsibility to select or poll the FDs.

Comment: `select()` and `poll()` are good for single threaded applications. It allows the code to handle multiple file descriptors (sockets). Blocking I/O is easier to write but not good on single process, single threaded codes. Use multiple process or multiple threads.

Comment: Is mine considered blocking I/O?

Comment: If you never set anything via `fcntl()`, then it is blocking I/O.

Comment: I see. So in my case, i would have to implement it by threading?

Comment: Yes. It will be wiser to use threads.

Comment: Do i have to re-setup everything for every thread that will be generated? such as `bind` `listen` ? or i will simply just have to make a thread that deals with every `socket` that i will generate? Because i implemented my server on a class. I tried using threads before that will generate instances of the server class per thread but it went total mess.

Comment: You can answer your latest question yourself by re-reading the man pages for bind() and listen(), and understanding what they do, then simply asking yourself the same question: does every thread need to do this?

Comment: If i a socket is open already then i believe you don't(?). My final concern now is by using `int result = recv(socketsManager[0],&command,1,0);`, is it specific that `socketsManager[0]` will only check the data sent to it? what if the other socket belonging to `socketsManager[1]` also sent a data? will `socketsManager[0]` also receive it or it has to wait until the looper is at `socketsManager[1]`?

Comment: They aren't reading the same socket, are they?

Comment: oops and nope. both diff sockets

Comment: The `accept()` statement returns different sockets per accepted connections.

Comment: and yes, so it means that `socketsManager[0]` won't get the data that is intended for `socketsManager[1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems with what you're doing:

1. You're pushing to socketsManager vector indefinitely. It won't be long before you run out of memory / file descriptors.
2. Protect access to socketsManager with some lock, else you can have race condition.

One way to do this is to use event loop:

- Have one or more threads for doing I/O.
- Each I/O thread operates on a list of open sockets.
- It uses select() or poll() to figure out which socket amongst the set it is operating on has data available. Invokes the necessary callbacks with the data that was read.
- Processing the data is handled by worker threads. The callback invoked one of the worker thread which processes the data.

References:
http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/121930298932/c-futures-at-instagram (see non-blocking IO section)